# Creating service (demon) applications

Tags: windows-phone-7, service

Is it possible to create a service type applications in Windows Phone 7? Can there be a resident app that has no UI, but active all the time in the background?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. You can create background applications only if you work for Microsoft or an OEM. Currently, all 3rd party developer apps get 'tombstoned', i.e. their process is no longer active, just some state information can optionally be saved, when the user navigates away from the application.

Comment: No longer true when Mango comes out (Fall 2011)

Answer (score 4):

Not possible. Non-Microsoft applications cannot run in the background.

The only thing you can do is handle push notifications.  Multi tasking for 3rd party developers is supposedly coming soon though.

Here is some good info:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Learn/Courses/WP7TrainingKit/WP7Silverlight/UsingPushNotificationsLab

> WP doesn’t allow your application to run code in a background process, which means your application can’t poll some web service for information. Push Notification compensate for that restriction and allows you to send messages to a Windows Phone device even if your application is not currently running.

Here is more information regarding other options like tombstoning (but I don't think you just want to suspend):

http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/07/15/understanding-the-windows-phone-application-execution-model-tombstoning-launcher-and-choosers-and-few-more-things-that-are-on-the-way-part-1.aspx

Comment: +1. I'd take the 3rd multi-tasking 'coming soon' news with a grain of salt, especially if you're an AT&T user :-)

Comment: @Praetorian I agree, don't expect to see it anytime soon :)

Answer (score 0):

I think these answers should be revised, apparently the latest release of Mango permits the use of Services..

Here's an article on the subject - [Leveraging Background Services and Agents in Windows Phone 7 (Mango)](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/11/23/leveraging-background-services-and-agents-in-windows-phone-7-mango.aspx)